# C# Storing original positions of Tab Pages within a Tab Control

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I'm relatively new to C# and I'm trying to use a tab control which has 5 tab pages within it.  These tab pages are displayed and hidden when required and I am able to re-add pages to the required position e.g. tabPage 2 should be re-added between tabPage1 and tabPage3 by passing in a number relating to the position I want it to appear in and swapping the pages around. How do I store the original positions of the tabPages and then just say tabPage2 should be added in to tabPage2's stored position?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where would you store the positions?  Is this to save the layout between runs of your application?

Comment: I just want to store the positions whilst the application is still running so that if the user clicks a buttons for example one of the tabpages that has been hidden will be redisplayed in its original position to ensure consistency in its position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the original position in the Tag property.  Some logic is required because neither page 1 nor 3 might be present.  This ought to be close:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int page = 0; page < tabControl1.TabCount; ++page)
            tabControl1.TabPages[page].Tag = page;
    }

    private List<TabPage> hiddenPages = new List<TabPage>();

    public void ShowTab(TabPage page) {
        int pos = (int)page.Tag;
        int insertPoint;
        for (insertPoint = 0; insertPoint < tabControl1.TabCount; ++insertPoint) {
            if (pos <= (int)tabControl1.TabPages[insertPoint].Tag) break;
        }
        tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(insertPoint, page);
        hiddenPages.Remove(page);
    }
}
```